# Getting hash with symbol as keys for mongo in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

The Mongo ruby driver seems to get put your results into a hash with strings as keys.  Is there a way to tell it to convert the keys into symbols instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [FAQ](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/file.FAQ.html), Even though there is a symbol type in Mongo, and you can store symbols in values, the BSON format specifies that keys must be strings.

Comment: That's really not the "rails" way.  I wonder why they made this decision.  Using symbols as keys is so much more convenient...

Comment: @etang - BSON is completely separate from Rails which is why they didn't do it the "rails" way, perhaps a rails-mongo gem is needed for you? :)

Comment: Mongoid (https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid) is the gem that you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a `Hash` that is keyed with strings, and you want to be able to use `Symbol`s as keys to access its values, you can use a [`HashWithIndifferentAccess`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html). If you are not using Rails, you can get this class via the `ActiveSupport` gem.

```
my_hash = { 'name' => 'Joe', 'email' => 'joe@schmoe.com' }
my_hash = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new my_hash
puts my_hash[:name] # "Joe"
```

Comment: Interesting... how does it store them internally? If you passed one to Mongo, would the keys be strings or symbols?

Comment: [Here's the code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/hash_with_indifferent_access.rb). Looks like it uses `String`s internally to store the data, and when you try to access values with a `Symbol` it converts it to a `String` to look up the data. So the keys are stored as `String`s for purposes of iterating the keys, etc.

Comment: That's pretty neat! Would work well in this particular use case.